# jQuery toggle dropdown menu with toggle arrow

Tags: drop-down-menu, jquery

I'm trying to do a vertical menu with dropdowns that can be activated by an arrow toggle, while still keeping the top level link active and clickable. I'm using a custom CMS so I have some constraints as far as how I can make this work.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li class="tn_first">
        <span></span><a class="topmenu" href="/default.asp">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tn_mid">
        <span></span><a class="topmenu" href="/listings.asp">My Listings</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li class="sn_first">
                <a class="submenu" href="#">Listing 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sn_mid">
                <a class="submenu" href="#">Listing 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sn_last">
                <a class="submenu" href="#">Listing 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
    <li class="tn_last">
        <span></span><a class="topmenu" href="/links.asp">System Pages</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li class="sn_first">
                <a class="submenu" href="#">Page 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sn_mid">
                <a class="submenu" href="#">Page 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sn_last">
                <a class="submenu" href="#">Page 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>               
</ul>
```

So I've got a pretty straightforward UL LI menu system. I've added to the template of the top level nav a span tag, which I wanted to use as a toggle switch. The span can be changed to anything, it's just what I have in there currently.

The issue I've run into is that given this is a template system, I have the option of putting the span in, but don't have the option to show it conditionally based on whether ul.subnav exists in the same li. So I need some way of applying display:block to the ones that actually meet this condition, then I'll just display:none the other spans by default.

I tried using this solution and it did work to a point, but it doesn't work with multiple dropdowns, it only seems to work if you have a single instance of a dropdown in your menu structure.

[jQuery Toggle Dropdown Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761648/jquery-toggle-dropdown-menu) 
and
http://jsfiddle.net/hXNnD/1/

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

var subMenu = jQuery("li ul li");
var linkClick = jQuery("ul li").filter(":has(ul)");

subMenu.hide();

linkClick.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    subMenu.slideToggle("fast");
});
});
```

I created another example that has 2 sub ULs so you can see where the code is falling down.

http://jsfiddle.net/BxsEX/

Answer (score 1):

Hide with CSS your spans and go for: `$('.topnav li:has(ul) span').show();`

http://jsbin.com/ujoqek/1/edit

CSS:

```
.topnav li span{ display:none; }
```

jQ:

```
var arrow = ['&#9660;','&#9650;'];

$('.topnav li:has(ul) span').show().html( arrow[0] ).data('a',0);
$('.topnav li > ul').hide();

$('.topnav span').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle();
  var arrw = $(this).data('a');
  $(this).html( arrow[++arrw%2] ).data('a', arrw); 
});
```

Comment: That's almost exactly it. All that's missing is to close the first UL when a second UL is opened.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is all you wanted. I may be wrong.

```
$('li').each(function(){ 
    //if we can find a UL with the class of subnav within our LI
    if($(this).find('ul.subnav').length){ 
        //find the span within this LI and give it a display block
        $(this).find('span').css('display', 'block')
    }else{
        //otherwise, hide the span.
        $(this).find('span').css('display', 'none')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this does solve my span issue, though I still have the issue of the other toggle code from the other thread not working with multiple sub ULs. I'm posting the code from the JSFiddle above to look at if you have a chance.